# Disable Desktop Support Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

So, I wanted to try desktop development in `Flutter`. I went through all steps and successfully enabled desktop support for `Flutter` using `flutter config --enable-linux-desktop` in `master channel`.

Now everytime I create a new project in `Flutter`, it automatically builds necessary files for `Linux Desktop`.

I tried running `flutter config --disable-linux-desktop`, but there is no command like that. **How do I disable desktop support?**

**PS** : I don't want to switch to `stable channel` since I also want to make my apps for `Web`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can disable enabled flags with adding `no-` prefix to the enable command. For disabling linux desktop flag you can simply run `flutter config --no-enable-linux-desktop`.

Comment: That works, thank you! I never imagined a command like this, starting with `no`, instead of `disable`. Also, didn't find anything in `docs` too. Thanks again!

Comment: @DetainedDeveloper Agreed, `disable` is the first thing I tried as well.. if the command was called `disable` that'd save a lot of people from searching on the internet I suppose.

Comment: Worked but then I had to remove the linux folder manually.

Answer (score 33):

Here are the terminal commands to disable the desktop support for your flutter projects.

**macOS:**

```
flutter config --no-enable-macos-desktop
```

**Windows:**

```
flutter config --no-enable-windows-desktop
```

**Linux:**

```
flutter config --no-enable-linux-desktop
```

New Project with flutter will have these platforms disabled like this

[image: New Flutter Project with Android Studio]

Comment: Will this work on existing Flutter projects?

Comment: @SethuSenthil no and if you want to remove any platform, you can simply delete the folder.

Answer (score 4):

```
flutter config --no-enable-web

flutter config --no-enable-macos-desktop

flutter config --no-enable-ios

flutter config --no-enable-android

flutter config --no-enable-linux-desktop

flutter config --no-enable-windows-desktop
```

Use these commands in terminal to disable build and support for specific platform in a project and the remove the specific folder of the platform from code editor

like in the following screen shot remove the specific folders after running above commands

[image]

Comment: The folder didnt go away.

Comment: Yes, delete the folder manually